# Entity Framework - get multiple results from an SQL statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

With EF I can return a collection of objects like so

```
entities.Customers.ToArray();
```

And I can include other tables, so I can effectively get 2 result sets back in the one query

```
entities.Customers.Include("Invoice").ToArray();
```

or if I have some custom SQL I can achive a similar result:

```
SqlDataReader reader = GetReaderFromSomewhere("SELECT * FROM Customer");
entities.Translate<Customer>(reader).ToArray();
```

But how do I get *multiple* results back from my own SQL? What I was thinking was something like this

```
SqlDataReader reader = GetReaderFromSomewhere("SELECT Customer.Name AS CustomerName, Invoice.Number AS InvoiceNumber FROM Customer JOIN Invoice ON Customer.ID = Invoice.CustomerID");
entities.Translate<Customer>(reader).Include<Invoice>().ToArray();
```

In the above example I have prefixed all the returned data with the table name so that the Translate method can know which columns belong to which tables. I'm presuming the Tranlate method does not support this but EF must do something similar when the include method is called. So my question is, how can I get the functionality of Include when using Translate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can not do that manually. What EF does is, it dynamically generate a class based on the LINQ query(and the Includes) that can materialize entities. Basically this class knows which columns will be mapped to which properties.

However you can use a micro ORM like [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) which can do [Multi Mapping](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/#Multi_Mapping). But this will only work for querying. So change tracking and CUD operations will not be available.

Comment: So the only solution is to write something yourself? Not the answer I wanted of course but that is an answer and allows me to move forward. I might look at writing something. It doesn't look like it would be too complicated (famous last words? :-) Thanks for the reply, I will mark it as the answer if a solution doesn't appear in a day or so.